# GRUB não aparece no boot do pc

Tags: ubuntu

O problema é o seguinte: eu tenho 3 partições: uma pra backup, outra para o Windows 10, e a outra pro Windows 8.1. Como gostei do W10, e queria instalar o Ubuntu, formatei a partição do 8.1 e instalei o Ubuntu lá. Mas depois disso, o GRUB não funciona. Na hora que o computador é ligado, só mostra uma tela roxa, mas sem as opções de boot; passa uns 3 segundos e a tela roxa some e já entra no Ubuntu direto. Já fiz todos os processos de instalar o GRUB pelo terminal, mas não dá em nada (vírgula, só me deu dor de cabeça pra tentar sair de um prompt, tive que ir pra live), já instalei pela Central do Ubuntu, também não funcionou.

Alguém me dá uma luz? rs

Comment: Kaleb, tente fazer sua pergunta no http://askubuntu.com/ ou no http://ubuntuforum-br.org. Aqui é muito improvável que consiga esta resposta, porque não se trata de uma dúvida sobre programação.